# Scan / Update operation statistics on DB2 and Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, db2

I am looking for a way to get statistics from both Oracle and DB2 databases for select/update/insert/delete operations count performed on every table. To say in other way, I would like to know how many scan operations were performed on given table vs. how many modifying operations were executed.

I had found that it is possible to it do in MS SQL Server as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

The reason I need it, is because it provides reasonable statistic if it is worthwhile to apply compression for a given table. The better the scan / update ratio - the better candidate the table is. I think this also holds true for other databases.

So is it possible to get these statistics in Oracle or/and DB2 ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer applies to the DB2 database engines for Linux, UNIX, and Windows (LUW) platforms, not DB2 for iSeries (AS/400) or DB2 for z/OS, which have significantly different engine internals than the LUW platforms. All of the documentation links I've included reference version 9.7 of DB2 for LUW.

DB2 for LUW provides extensive performance and utilization statistics in every version of the data engine, including the no-cost [DB2 Express-C](http://ibm.com/db2/express) product. The collection of these statistics is governed by a series of database engine settings called [system monitor switches](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/c0005719.html). The statistics you seek involve the table monitor switch, and possibly also the statement and UOW (unit of work) monitor switches. When those system monitor switches are enabled, you can retrieve running totals of various performance gauges and counters from [snapshot monitors](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/c0006003.html) or by selecting from [administrative SQL views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0006117.html) (in the SYSIBMADM schema) that present the same snapshot monitor output as SQL result sets. The snapshot monitors incur less system overhead than [event monitors](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0005993.html), which run in the background as a trace and store a stream of detailed information to special tables or files.

Compression is a [licensed feature](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/linux-unix-windows/editions_features_storage.html) that alters the internal storage of tables and indexes all the way from the tablespace to the buffer pool (RAM cache) to the transaction log file. In most cases, the additional CPU overhead of compression and decompression is more than offset by the overall reduction in I/O. The [deep row compression feature](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0056481.html) compresses rows in tables by building and using a 12-bit dictionary of multi-byte patterns that can even cross column boundaries. Enabling deep row compression for a table typically reduces its size by 40% or more before DBA intervention. Indexes are [compressed](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0054539.html) through a shorthand algorithm that exploits their sorted nature by omitting common leading bytes between the current and previous index keys.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle you can see how many update/delete/inserts have been on a table in sys.dba_tab_modifications. The data is flushed to the table every 4 hours. For the reads you can use dba_hist_seg_stat, part of AWR. Use of this is licensed.
sys.dba_tab_modifications is reset once a table gets new optimizer statistics.